# What is the cleanest way to have "Empty" option in a combobox in Extjs6?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a basic combobox backed by an ajax store. I want to be able to select an empty value from the combo as an option (it doesn't exist as a record in a store). Setting `emptyText: 'None'` would be perfect, the only problem is that once you selected some value you can't select an empty one anymore.

Is there a better option than listening to store load and injecting extra empty records, or something of that nature. I don't want to permanently have empty records in that store, only when used in certain comboboxes.

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    queryMode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    forceSelection: true,
    editable: false,
    emptyText: 'None',
    store: 'MyStore',
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved this by creating a plugin.

```
Ext.define("App.ux.plugin.form.field.EmptiableComboBox", {
    extend : 'Ext.AbstractPlugin',
    alias : 'plugin.emptiableCombo',
    init : function(combo) {
        this.combo = combo;
        this.callParent();
        combo.addListener('change', function() {
            if (this.getValue() === null || this.getValue() == '') {
                this.reset();
                this.setRawValue(null);
                this.lastSelection = [];
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and here is how i used it.

```
{   
    type:'combobox',
    typeAhead:true,
    plugins: ['emptiableCombo'],
    listConfig:{
        cls:'x-combo-boundlist-small'
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I have been through this exercise earlier and for sure we don't want to add an empty value option. So we are left with 2 options

1. Add a Clear Trigger for the Combos that can be Emptied.
2. Make the Combobox Editable and enable forceSelection, this way it is easy for user to type in values for auto selection as well as he has an ability to clear the values if the field is optional. With forceSelection on, the user cannot enter arbitrary values.

And we went with option 2 and created this plugin. Do post it here if you come up with any other better solution. Thx.

Comment: I like the clear trigger option, didn't think of that. I think that's what I will do. Thanks.

Comment: Hai, @JChap , I tried But its not working for me, [see Here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1r3p)

Comment: And can you please look into [this issue too] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42511573/unable-to-bind-the-id-of-the-combobox-field-on-grid-update)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:

```js
Ext.define('Ext.form.field.EmptyableComboBox', {
  extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',

  xtype: 'emptyable_combobox',

  uses: [ 'Ext.view.BoundList' ],

  /** The source is used to hold the original store. */
  _source: null,

  editable: false, // must pick from an item in the list
  allowBlank: true, // obviously can't be required, as the user can reset to blank.

  initComponent: function() {
    this._source = this.getStore();

    var newData = [ 
      this._toEntry(null, null)
    ];

    this._source.each(function(record) {
      newData.push(this._toEntry(record.get(this.valueField), record.get(this.displayField)));
    }, this)

    this.store = new Ext.data.Store({
      fields: [ this.valueField, this.displayField ],
      data: newData
    });


    var itemCls = Ext.view.BoundList.prototype.itemCls;
    var innerTpl = Ext.view.BoundList.prototype.getInnerTpl;
    this.listConfig = Ext.apply({
      tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
          '<ul class="' + Ext.plainListCls + '">',
          '<tpl for=".">',
            '<li role="option" unselectable="on" class="' + itemCls + '">',
              '<tpl if="name == null">',
                '<em>' + this.emptyText + '</em>',
              '<tpl else>',
                innerTpl(this.displayField),
              '</tpl>',
            '</li>',
            '<tpl if="name == null">',
              '<hr />',
            '</tpl>',
          '</tpl>',
          '</ul>'
        )
    }, this.listConfig);

    this.callParent(arguments);
  },

  _toEntry: function(value, display) {
    var result = {}
    result[this.valueField] = value;
    result[this.displayField] = display;
    return result;
  }
})
```

If you need to support filtering on the original store, you'll need to do something a little more sophisticated, but this should point you in the wright direction.

Note that if your ComboBox is `editable` (e.g. you allow the user to type in it), they can do an empty value simply by clearing the text. That's why this implementation hard-codes the `editable` value to false.